# Declaration missing ; and , expected error

Tags: turbo-c++

I don't know whats going wrong with following code.

```
#ifndef LLIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LLIST_H_INCLUDED
// header content goes here

typedef int Element_Type;

struct LinkNode;

typedef LinkNode * Node_Ptr;

struct LinkNode
{
    Element_Type data_member;
    Node_Ptr    link_member; 
};

#endif
```

I made a header file of above code and place that file in "include" directory. But whenever I am trying to compile code, it fires following two errors.

`1. , expected`
`2. Declaration missing ;`

**Edit**

Another approach I used is

```
typedef int Element_Type;

struct LinkNode
{
    Element_Type data_member;
    LinkNode * link_member;
}* node_Ptr;
```

This fires `declaration expected ;` at line `LinkNode * link_member` line

[image]

Any help would be greater pleasure.

Comment: Why are you defining LinkNode 3 times?

Comment: Structs can reference pointers to themselves (at least they used to...)

Comment: If i don't do then also it is firing `declaration missing ;` error. Just providing typo for declaration, i am defining it.

Comment: @Jim, any solution? Facing trouble in solving error. Can't understand what goes wrong.

Comment: I can't get it to fail with g++.

Comment: Try it with single LinkNode struct definition and LinkNode* instead of Node_ptr.

Comment: Are you sure this is what is failing?  Maybe the include directory isn't being seen.

Comment: @Jim, I had attached a screen shot of my code.

Comment: OK, I think I get it know.  Leave off the * node_Ptr (just leave ;) and add the line:  struct LinkNode *node_Ptr.

Comment: shoot try:  struct LinkNode * link_member;   Since you aren't going typedef, you HAVE to say struct whenever you mention LinkNode.

Comment: You are amazing my friend. You solve my problem. If you want, you can post your answer. I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct LinkNode  
{  
    Element_Type data_member;  
    struct LinkNode * link_member;  
}* node_Ptr;
```

This should fix it.  (NOTE: It's possible that TurboC++ is more restrictive on dealing with structs than other C++ compilers (like g++).  It seems to be evaluating them more strictly.